# Simple through-hole voltage supervisor

Tags: solar-cell, esp8266, supercapacitor, supervisor

I'm trying to power a microcontroller (ESP8266) from a solar cell and a supercapacitor. It might or might not make sense, but it's a hobby project.

The thing is - ESP8266 doesn't boot if the voltage is brought up from 0 gradually. Either the main microcontroller or the flash memory fail to get in an operational state when the solar cell is slowly charging the supercap.

I've tried using a supervisor to toggle its EN pin, but apparently that doesn't work either, and even if it did work, I'm fairly confident the narrow hysteresis of the supervisor would make it unusable.

The MCU in question draws upwards of 70 mA when in normal operation (let's say 100 mA to be safe). I don't really need it to run "forever", and its nominal operational range is from 3.6V down to 2.5V. I'm perfectly fine, for what I want to do with it, if it turns on at 3.6V and then depletes the supercap (or not, depending on sunlight and my 150 mA nominal solar cell) until it reaches 2.5V.

I've searched around for a supervisor with such a range but can't find anything simple-ish and through-hole. Is there a simple way, with through-hole components, to make a supervisor-like circuit with a large hysteresis, which would power the MCU?

Comment: Use an smd to through hole pcb. Supervisor circuits are weird since they need to use references yet run properly at low but indeterminant voltages.

Comment: It's worth learning to deal with the simpler leaded SMD packages, otherwise you're just going to be locked out of too much of current technology.   Thinking outside the box, there are DIP-8 ATtiny's that could be made to do something using their own capabilities then go to sleep.  Of course that also points to maybe changing chips unless you need the ESP for wifi.

Comment: power the ESP through a mosfet, using Vgs(th) to control the point it turns on. You can feed the gate with a resistor divider and/or zener to make sure that Vds is higher than Vgs.

Comment: @dandavis Even though MOSFETs have steep turn-on, it's still not really vertical, and I don't see how it helps me on the down path - when the supercap gets depleted?

Comment: you can go into deep sleep once done sending, which uses negligible power. A schmitt trigger optocoupler can also "digitize"  the slow ramp up into a discrete off/on. You might even find one that can power the ESP w/o a FET.